# 16 Spaces Lucky Wheel

Tags: jquery

So I'm betting on a virtual LuckyWheel and I want to know if its rigged or not. This is the wheel :

[image]

The wheel only rotates between 3600deg and 6120deg.

The code that gives the degrees to the wheel to roll is this one:

```
(function($) {
var $fortune = function(args) {
    if (args === undefined) {
        throw new Error("You must define the options.prices")
    }
    var options = $.extend({}, {
        prices: args,
        duration: 1e3 * 4,
        separation: 2,
        min_spins: 10,
        max_spins: 15,
        onSpinBounce: function() {}
    }, args);
    var fortune = this;
    var prices_amount = Array.isArray(options.prices) ? options.prices.length : options.prices;
    var prices_delta = 360 / prices_amount;
    var is_spinning = false;
    fortune.spin = function(price) {
        price = typeof price === "number" ? price : Math.floor(Math.random() * prices_amount);
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        var position = Math.floor(prices_delta * (price - 1 / 2) + randomBetween(options.separation, prices_delta - options.separation));
        var spins = randomBetween(options.min_spins, options.max_spins);
        var final_position = 360 * spins + position;
        var prev_position = 0;
        var is_bouncing = false;
        is_spinning = true;
        fortune.css({
            transform: "rotate(" + final_position + "deg)",
            "-webkit-transform": "rotate(" + final_position + "deg)",
            transition: "transform " + options.duration + "ms cubic-bezier(.17,.67,.12,.99)",
            "-webkit-transition": "-webkit-transform " + options.duration + "ms cubic-bezier(.17,.67,.12,.99)"
        }).siblings(".spin").removeClass("bounce");
        var bounceSpin = function() {
            var curPosition = Math.floor(getRotationDegrees(fortune)),
                mod = Math.floor((curPosition + prices_delta * .5) % prices_delta),
                diff_position, position_threshold = prices_delta / 5,
                distance_threshold = prices_delta / 10;
            prev_position = Math.floor(curPosition < prev_position ? prev_position - 360 : prev_position);
            diff_position = curPosition - prev_position;
            if (mod < position_threshold && diff_position < distance_threshold || mod < position_threshold * 3 && diff_position >= distance_threshold) {
                if (!is_bouncing) {
                    fortune.siblings(".spin").addClass("bounce");
                    options.onSpinBounce(fortune.siblings(".spin"));
                    is_bouncing = true
                }
            } else {
                fortune.siblings(".spin").removeClass("bounce");
                is_bouncing = false
            }
            if (is_spinning) {
                prev_position = curPosition;
                requestAnimationFrame(bounceSpin)
            }
        };
        var animSpin = requestAnimationFrame(bounceSpin);
        setTimeout(function() {
            fortune.css({
                transform: "rotate(" + position + "deg)",
                "-webkit-transform": "rotate(" + position + "deg)",
                transition: "",
                "-webkit-transition": ""
            }).siblings(".spin").removeClass("bounce");
            cancelAnimationFrame(animSpin);
            deferred.resolve(Array.isArray(options.prices) ? options.prices[price] : price);
            is_spinning = false
        }, options.duration);
        return deferred.promise()
    };
    var getRotationDegrees = function(obj) {
        var angle = 0,
            matrix = obj.css("-webkit-transform") || obj.css("-moz-transform") || obj.css("-ms-transform") || obj.css("-o-transform") || obj.css("transform");
        if (matrix !== "none") {
            var values = matrix.split("(")[1].split(")")[0].split(","),
                a = values[0],
                b = values[1],
                radians = Math.atan2(b, a);
            if (radians < 0) {
                radians += 2 * Math.PI
            }
            angle = Math.round(radians * (180 / Math.PI))
        }
        return angle
    };
    var randomBetween = function(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min
    };
    return fortune
};
$.extend($.fn, {
    fortune: $fortune
})
```

So, I see that there's the `(Math.random() * prices_amount)` and the `(prices_delta * (price - 1 / 2) + randomBetween(options.separation, prices_delta - options.separation)` but what I really want to know is why all this calculations? Is this completly random or its rigged when someone bets higher values, in this case, higher "prices"?

I couldn't analyze this code because I'm not a programmer so there I'm asking to you guys. If you need more information about the wheel to analyze better, tell me!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From a brief read, the bulk of this code is a function `fortune.spin` that takes a list of prices and a parameter `price`. It will always first spin the wheel. If the parameter is not set, it does its best to pick a random position to land on. If the parameter is set to 1, it will always land on price 1, etc. The decision where the wheel will end up is taken in the first line of the function. The remaining code (and randomization) is just to make the animation play smoothly and show some variation in how it plays.

Comment: So, basically, its rigged?
The wheel can be rolled with a 0 bet. When I click "spin" with google "inspect element" open, it shows me a degree (for example 4545deg) then the degree disapears when the wheel stops.

But when I bet another vallue it will roll also random degrees (i think). But maybe the final position will be always the same?

If you want I can make a quick youtube video demonstrating the wheel.

Comment: Hard to say. It feels like it's prepared to be rigged. I do not see the code that calls the `spin` function, though - only if `spin` called with a number, the result will be predetermined. Otherwise, it will be pretty random.

Comment: Heres a 40 sec. video where you can see the wheel spining (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rlEid8dYWBU).

All the bets were with 0 coins. You can see that when I spin, it calculates a degree between 3600 and 6120. I think each spin, the wheel starts always from the 0deg position. The thing is, maybe with higher bets this "degree" will be maybe rigged?

If the video doesn't help much, thanks for helping Christoph!